# Wordpress [Plugin: Event Post Type] How to arrange posts by event date instead of posted?

Tags: wordpress

Currently using the Wordpress Plugin [Event Post Type] and the posts are currently ordered by when I post them. I really need them ordered by event date which the plugin adds to the post type for me.

I am currently using this code and am not sure how to get it to order:

```
<div id="events-teaser"><?php
                        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => '_date_start', 'order' => 'DESC' );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                            <div class="teaser-event <?php echo do_shortcode('[xydac_field]promo[/xydac_field]'); ?>">
                            <div class="event-meta gold">
                            <div class="event-date"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_date_start", true); ?></div>
                            <div class="event-time"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_time_start", true); ?></div></div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><div class="event-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div><?php
                        endwhile; else:
                        ?><p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a call to query_posts() in one of your Template files before The Loop begins. The wp_query object will generate a new SQL query using your parameters. When you do this, WordPress ignores the other parameters it receives via the URL (such as page number or category). If you want to preserve that information, you can use the $query_string global variable in the call to query_posts().

For example, to set the display order of the posts without affecting the rest of the query string, you could place the following before The Loop:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
```

change its order from 'ASC' to whatever you want.

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything.. :(